# Clone section not allowing jQuery from original page to fire

Tags: jquery, find, clone, toggleclass

I have a page that I am using to store some assets I need to load on other pages with jQuery. One section of that page in particular has an inline script that I needed to pull to another page. I am also executing a click event on the title of that page:

```
$('.blogList.archive > ul > li > h2.postTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('expand');
    });
```

The method I am using to pull the section mentioned has an inline script so I used this method to get the section from the page:

```
$.get('assets.html', function(data) {
    $('#sidebar').html($('<section></section>').html(data).find('.sidebar').clone());
    });
```

The first function (.toggleClass) is working fine on the assets page, but when I clone it, the function no longer works.

I am working on this, but cannot find a solution. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blogList.archive > ul > li > h2.postTitle').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('expand');
    });
change in 

$('.blogList.archive > ul > li > h2.postTitle').on("click",function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('expand');
    });
```

reference [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I tried that prior too posting, but the syntax was a bit off. I tried your example to no avail. A note I am using Zepto js. Foundation is our platform of choice. Will that have any effect?

Comment: jquery.noconflict() if chance of conflict with your js  see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: .noConflict doesn't seem to be the issue either. I'm curious if it could be something different. Just before this code is this: $('h2.posTitle').addClass('expand'); It's not being fired either.

Comment: After some troubleshooting with suggestions we found it best that we approach this from a different angle. I appreciate the help.